# How to delete Exported folder (SSH)

Tags: bash, ssh, centos

I have used command:

```
export TMPDIR=$HOME/tmp
```

Now it created /tmp folder in my root directory (root/tmp)

How can i delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the environment variable or the directory itself?
To remove the directory itself (and all the files in it) do:

```
rm -r $HOME/tmp
```

To remove the environment variable do:

```
unset TMPDIR
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -r $HOME/tmp
```

will delete the contents of the directory and then delete the directory.